# Highcharts when giving Json value it is not rendering

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, json, highcharts

I'm using `highcharts` to create charts in `asp.net webforms`. I make an ajax call to a web service which in return gives me a json result which only includes the title name.

If I send this value hard coded to the charts method it works perfectly but when I put json data instead of a hard coded title the chart does not render.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "OssmWebService.asmx/FillChart",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: JSON.stringify(mWhereParam),
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data1) {
  var a = data1.d[0];    
    Highcharts.chart('container1', {

        title: a.titlename,

        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: thesolarfoundation.com'
        },

        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Number of Employees'
            }
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'middle'
        },

        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                pointStart: 2010
            }
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'Installation',
            data: [43934, 52503, 57177, 69658, 97031, 119931, 137133, 154175]
        }, {
            name: 'Manufacturing',
            data: [24916, 24064, 29742, 29851, 32490, 30282, 38121, 40434]
        }, {
            name: 'Sales & Distribution',
            data: [11744, 17722, 16005, 19771, 20185, 24377, 32147, 39387]
        }, {
            name: 'Project Development',
            data: [null, null, 7988, 12169, 15112, 22452, 34400, 34227]
        }, {
            name: 'Other',
            data: [12908, 5948, 8105, 11248, 8989, 11816, 18274, 18111]
        }]

    });
```

Data which is coming in success of ajax:

```
"{ text: 'Basic Requirement' }"
```

If I put this data and hard coded in the title property it work fines but if I give this data directly to property like I did in the above code

```
a = data1.d[0];
title: a.titlename;
```

My C# code

```
[WebMethod]
public List<sampleDatalist> FillChart(string arrSelectedValues)
{
    List<sampleDatalist> sample = new List<sampleDatalist>();
    sample.Add(new sampleDatalist { titlename = "{ text: 'Basic Requirement' }" });
    return sample;
}

public class sampleDatalist
{
    public string titlename;
}
```

It's showing like this if I give json data
[image: Chart with errors in console]

Update : 
As bob suggested to convert my properties to object therefore

My C# will be

```
  [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public List<sampleDatalist> FillChart(string arrSelectedValues)
    {
        Object a = " { text: 'Basic Requirement' }";

        List<sampleDatalist> smList = new List<sampleDatalist>();
        smList.Add(new sampleDatalist { titlename = a });

        return smList;



    }

public class sampleDatalist
{
    public Object titlename;

}
```

Problem still remain same.

Comment: `titlename = "{ text: 'Basic Requirement' }"` is going to be serialized into a string, not a property. That is, it'll generate `titlename: '{text: \'Basic Requirement\' }'` rather than `titlename: { text: 'Basic Requirement' }`. Make `titlename` an object, rather than a string.

Comment: @Rob How do i make object?

Comment: You give it the type `object`. Or give it a proper class with properties such as `text`. Then you use it just like you've used `sampleDataList`..

Comment: I have give the type Object but still same problem @Rob

Comment: You are probably still assigning a string to it..

Comment: @Rob see my edit

Comment: Yes.. you are still assigning a string.

Comment: Where? can you plz explain in detail answer how should i send it? @Rob